# Is there any other way to make the date that can be selected like datetime-local in js?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the datetime-local but my teacher say there is a better way for the date that can be selected is using JavaScript.I searched in google but only have writing out today date.Does it have in js?

Answer (score 0):

Google 'Javascript Date Picker'
A few examples:

- https://mcdatepicker.netlify.app/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-datepicker
- https://easepick.com/
- https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

All offer improvements / addition features.
It depends on what you want to use, what your use case is and how complicated you want the interactions to be.

Look at any of 'getting started' links on these for a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

What about a simple `<input type="date">`?

```html
<input type="date" >
```